# change UIButton default action by gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton

I can't understand the expression in [Event Handling Guide for iOS－Interacting with Other User Interface Controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW21)

> If you have a custom subclass of one of these controls and you want to change the >default action, attach a gesture recognizer directly to the control instead of to >the parent view. Then, the gesture recognizer receives the touch event first.

anyone can give me some example? thx

Comment: The statement seems pretty clear. Explicitly add a gesture recognizer to your specific control. I'm not sure why it even has to be a custom control.  I'd just try doing that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass the `UIButton` attach the gesture recognizer.

In CustomButton.m

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                              initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handleTap
{
    NSLog(@"Button tapped twice");
}
```

In your ViewController initiate the button and add as subview

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomButton.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CustomButton *customButton = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 150.0f, 100.0f)];
    [customButton setTitle:@"Tap Twice" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    customButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:customButton];

}
```

Generally button works on single tap.we are changing the default behaviour of the button by adding tap gesture recognizer and number of taps by 2.

Comment: thx a lot!! I misunderstand the 'the parent view', i thought it is the button (orz)